# How to copy cells from one excel file and append it at the end of another file which already has data using python

Tags: python, excel

How do I copy cells from one excel file and append it at the end of another file which already has data using python using xlrd. I am able to load the files and read the contents of the cell but i want to copy the cell values from a file (say A.xlsx) and append the values in another excel file (say B.xlsx) which already has data. I would like to append the data at the end of the current data in file B.xlsx

```
import os 
import xlrd

def openxlfile(): 

    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename = "C:\\A\\A.xlsx") 
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename = "C:\\B\\B.xlsx") 
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0) 
    print(worksheet.cell_value(3,8))

openxlfile()
```

Comment: Please add the code you've written so far along with the errors you've gotten when trying to run it. Also please see https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: import os
import xlrd

def openxlfile():
    workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename = "C:\\A\\A.xlsx")
 workbook = xlrd.open_workbook(filename = "C:\\B\\B.xlsx")
    worksheet = workbook.sheet_by_index(0)
    print(worksheet.cell_value(3,8))
 
openxlfile()

Comment: What do you mean by append to the end of the file? Add data into the next set of cell or add the first cells together then the 2nd cells, etc.

Comment: for example : if excel file 'A.xlsx' has data till row 500 and column j. I would like to copy all the cells data from excel file 'B.xlsx' and paste it from row 501

Comment: were you able to figure out the problem? I too would like todo something similar to this